# Ubuntu Software Center did not pay me?

Tags: software-center

So, I believe USC should have paid me via Paypal the 20.80$ I earned by selling my game here.... But I did not get anything... Help? Someone clarify me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it cannot be answered by the community.

Answer (score 5):

[Talk to Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/about-canonical/contact).

We're a community support site, we're not going to have access to your relationship with Canonical and the USC, nor the power to do anything about it.